# Reviewing infobox on mobile devices

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

When reviewing on my phone, i noticed the info-box normally located at the sidebar is now at the bottom, suggesting choosing tasks "on the left" to get started.

Should it say "above" or should the box be at the top on mobile devices?

[image]